# Callback Function not defined on webview on the second run [flutter]

Tags: flutter, webview, android-webview

I have made a webView in flutter from another page, and a javascript channel `reportViewerInitializeEnded`

After i run and go back to the previous page, when i click on generating the webview again,this error happened:

`Uncaught TypeError: window.parent.ReportViewerInitializeEnded is not a function"`

Im not sure why the function worked the first time and not the second time.

Here is the code for starting the webview:

```
ReportViewerController reportController =
    ReportViewerController();
WebViewController webViewController = WebViewController();

webViewController
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..setBackgroundColor(Colors.white)
  ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
    onProgress: (int progress) {
      print("progress: $progress%");
    },
    onPageStarted: (String url) {},
    onPageFinished: (String url) {
      print("page load finished");
      webViewController.runJavaScript(
          "reportViewerInitialize('${responseList["Value"]}')");
    },
    onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
      print("web resource error");
    },
  ))
  ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(
      "${sessionInfo.ip}/ReportViewer/flex-report.html"));


Widget reportViewer = ReportViewer(
  key: ValueKey<double>(pageLoader.layer! + 11),
  reportController: reportController,
  webViewController: webViewController,
  programID: pageLoader.pgmID == ""
      ? pageLoader.savedPgmID
      : pageLoader.pgmID ?? "",
  webMode: pageLoader.webMode,
);
// navigate to a webview widget
pageLoader.goToPage(
    titleName: "",
    page: reportViewer,
    pgmID: pageLoader.pgmID == ""
        ? pageLoader.savedPgmID
        : pageLoader.pgmID ?? "",
    scrollController: ScrollController(),
    formData: FormData.createEmpty());
```

and here's the code for initState, and where i go back to the previous page and dispose the webview widget:

```
  void initState() {
      // add channels (callbacks from the report viewer)
      print("init");
      widget.webViewController
          .addJavaScriptChannel("ReportViewerInitializeEnded",
              onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) async {
        print("ReportViewerInitializeEnded");
      });
  }
 
  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.webViewController
        .removeJavaScriptChannel("ReportViewerInitializeEnded");
    widget.webViewController.clearCache();
    widget.webViewController.clearLocalStorage();
    super.dispose();
  }
```